# MappingException: Named query not known

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, named-query

Trying to learn Hibernate, i am trying to learn how to execute `NamedQuries` but evertime i am getting `Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known`.Please help me out here

**Error** (*only the message, not showing complete stack*)

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: hibernate_tut_emp.Employee.FindCountOfNames
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getNamedQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getNamedQuery(SessionImpl.java:1372)
    at hibernate_tut_emp.MyOps.main(MyOps.java:20)
```

**Employee.java**

```
package hibernate_tut_emp;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;



@Entity
@Table(name="Hib1")

@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="GetDetailsByName" , query="select * from hib1 h where h.name=:name"),
    @NamedQuery(name="FindCountOfNames", query="select count(1) as cnt from hib1 h where h.name=:name")
})
public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
            return name;
    }

    public void setName(String empName) {
            this.name = empName;
    }


}
```

**MyOps.java**

```
package hibernate_tut_emp;

import java.util.Scanner;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class MyOps {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a name : ");
        String name = scnr.next();

        SessionFactory ses = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = ses.openSession();

        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("hibernate_tut_emp.Employee.FindCountOfNames");


        query.setString("name", name);
        int count = ((Integer)query.iterate().next()).intValue();
        System.out.println("count : "+count);
    }
}
```

**employee.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hibernate_tut_emp.Employee" table="hib1">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string" column="name" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
         <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
         <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
         <property name="connection.username">root</property>
         <property name="connection.password">mayank</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
         <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
         <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
          <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
         <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
         <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
         <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

      <mapping class="hibernate_tut_emp.Employee" />
      <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>

     </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

I googled out everything possible but i think i am overlooking some basic stuff.Any indication in right direction is appreciated! :)

One thing i considered is that if i have defined in class file `NamedQueries`, i do not need to mention it in *xml* file.Please correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: Why do you use both a class and its annotations, and an xml file, todefine the mapping of the same class? Just use one of them (the class and its annotations, preferrably). Also note that both of the queries are incorrect. `*` is SQL, not HQL. HQL uses entity names (i.e. class names), and not table names. And `h` isn't defined in the second query.

Comment: @JBNizet : ok...so you mean if i have `annotations` in `Employee.java` i do not need `employee.hbm.xml`?

Comment: No, you don't need it. XML mapping was useful when annotations didn't exist (Java 4, we're at Java 8).

Comment: I would hazard a guess that because you are mapping the file using `employee.hbm.xml` any and all annotations are unceremoniously ignored. You need to remove all `hbm.xml` files and their references. Then you should begin to get startup errors due to your HQL being invalid.

Comment: @BoristheSpider : ok...that makes sense, i removed the mapping xml...not i am getting `Errors in named queries: GetDetailsByName` ...

Comment: Yup, now you need to read the [HQL documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) and write some valid queries. `HQL != SQL`!  Maybe start with `from Employee where name = :name`.

Comment: @JBNizet : i am now getting error that queries are wrong....i'll work out from here...thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. Your named queries should use entities not tables. If you want native queries you should use [NamedNativeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html) instead.
2. You don't need to supply the entity name when fetching the query.

   Change this:

   ```
   Query query = session.getNamedQuery("hibernate_tut_emp.Employee.FindCountOfNames");
   ```

   to:

   ```
   Query query = session.getNamedQuery("FindCountOfNames");
   ```

Comment: one question though...when i get the `SQL` query printed it print some other names like `Select employee_0_o ...` like that but table is mapped as `employee` only...is this normal?

Comment: That's after table name and it's the Hibernate table aliasing. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: but its not fetching me the desired output...i am using the `FindCountOfNames` named query, but irrespective of what i `set` to the `:name`, i am getting 0 as output...any ideas?

Comment: I think it's better to ask a new question with the exact current mapping and code example. Ping me when you're done.

Comment: then i'll ping you after 2 days! :D