# Hibernate Named query not know error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I dont know why but when I import this project to Eclipse. This work well.

So, I think this is problem of eclipse project when import to InteliJ IDEA

---

This not easy such my imagine.

I have class Setting and Setting.hbm.xml for mapping hibernate.
In this class:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Setting" table="setting" lazy="false">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>

    .....
</class>

<query name="select.setting">
    from Setting as s where s.id = ? order by s.name
</query>
```

Now, when I call function

```
this.getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery("select.setting", params);
```

This return error

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Named query not known: select.setting; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: select.setting
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:218) ~[spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:308) ~[spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.findByNamedQuery(HibernateTemplate.java:933) ~[spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
```

Please give advice about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate qtn.
Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084031/mappingexception-named-query-not-known

Comment: It not duplicate bro. Please check again

Comment: Does the name of the query without dot give the same result ? (Say : "selectSetting" instead of "select.setting", for example).

Comment: Have you included the `hbm` in the session?

Comment: Yes, I use spring boot and already set mapping
@Bean
 public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws Exception {
  LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
  sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
  sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
  sessionFactory.setMappingDirectoryLocations(new ClassPathResource[] {
    new ClassPathResource("data/model")
  });

Comment: Refer the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try with this.

```
<query name="select.setting">
    <![CDATA[from Setting as s where s.id = ? order by s.name]]>
</query>
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML parser gets confused of you are not using CDATA tag.
CDATA is way of telling the framework that its a data which should not be interpreted as a markup.

Hence as @Lovababu mentioned, include the query inside CDATA tags:

```
<query name="select.setting">
<![CDATA[from Setting as s where s.id = ? order by s.name]]>
```